# how to change wxpython grid layout direction?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, apache-phoenix

I am using wx. grid in a frame. The frame's direction is right to left with:

```
self. SetLayoutDirection(wx.Layout_RightToLeft)
```

The above code has effect on all childs so I am happy.  The grid is right to left too but not completely.  Rows labels are in right side but columns are aligned in left side and even cell(0,0) is shown in left side but accept text from right side of grid.  what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

These are just some of the limitations of the current, far from perfect, RTL support in `wxGrid`. It definitely needs to be improved, preferably by someone with experience of how things works in the RTL languages which, unfortunately, excludes all of the wxWidgets developers. Hopefully someone motivated to really fix this could contribute to it in the future.